# When do we have diminishing marginal returns to labor?

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, production-function

When we have a production function exhibiting constant returns to scale, with only labor and technology, why don't we have any diminishing marginal returns to labor?

Comment: Welcome! Pleae see our policy on homework question and the general FAQ.

Comment: @emeryville this is not a homework question. I read this in a text, but the text didn't provide explanation for this.

Comment: Okay, so please quote the text because it is important to give some context and be explicit.